# Jekyll - Liquid error: can't convert fixnum into String

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm using [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) with ruby 1.9.1; my page use the paginator object:

```
<li><a href="{{site.paginate_path | replace: ':num', page}}">{{page}}</a></li>
```

give me the following:

```
<li><a href="Liquid error: can't convert fixnum into String">2</a></li>
```

But jekyll build doesn't produce any error. When I'm trying trying with ruby 2.1.2, this error isn't happening *(but I don't want to update to ruby 2+, unless there is really no other solution)*.

I've tryied to add `.to_i` or `.to_s`, but I'm not to really understand how it works, and I still get some errors; I've tried the following:

```
<li><a href="{{site.paginate_path|replace: ':num', page.to_i}}">{{page}}</a></li>
<li><a href="{{site.paginate_path|replace: ':num', page.to_s}}">{{page}}</a></li>
```

In both cases, I get:

```
<li><a href="Liquid error: can't convert nil into String">2</a></li>
```

Is using `.to_i` or `.to_s` the way to fix my problem. Why doesn't it work ? Any ideas how I could debug this error ?

Thanks a lot for your help !!

Comment: What is the output you want? What you're trying is replacing the page number with the string page. Theoretically, this would result in having `pagepage` instead of `page2`.

Comment: ```site.paginate_path``` doesn't contain the page number. I'm trying to replace it with *the content of the ```page``` variable*; my expected result is ```page2```.

Comment: But `replace ':num', page` replaces occurences of `:num` with `page`. `page2` is already the standard format for pagination with Jekyll.

Comment: Since it was working for ruby 2+, it seems that ```replace``` is using the content of the ```page``` variable, not the ```page``` as a String. Anyway, it doesn't explain the error ```can't convert fixnum into String``` or how I can debug it, because I don't even get ```pagepage```, I got an error instead.

Comment: I still don't get your use case. Why are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is misleading. The method is erroneous, but Ruby 2+ has been made to ignore silly mistakes :) Thats a good news.

Simply ask what you want to know, maybe we could help

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's probably exactly that. Like I said, it's hard for me  to update anything (I'm using default debian packages, not the gems). But I've found a work-around, following @kleinfreund comment:

    ```<li><a href="/page{{page}}">{{page}}</a></li>```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue you're pointing to got fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/commit/6e967f7f3a26447f5a5708031ee8327635f3598c). Hence, using version 2.5.2+ of the liquid gem should solve the issue.